# Is there sampling process that admits computing a similarity of two densities when one is intractable?

Tags: density-function, similarities, divergence

I have two densities, $p, q$ with sample space $\mathbb{R}^n$, and we can assume both $p,q>0$ (full support). I can compute and sample from $q$. I can compute $p$ up to a constant and I cannot sample from $p$. (A general example is $p(t) = \exp(f(t))/Z$, where we cannot compute the normalization constant $Z = \int_t \exp(f(t))dt$ but we can compute $f(t)$ and, hence, can compute $p(t)Z = \exp(f(t))$.

My goal is to see if $p=q$, or more specifically (and rigorously) prove a true estimate of $\|p-q\|_1$ or equivalently the total variation of $P-Q$. I'm open to other similarity functions on densities such as KL divergence or $\ell(2)$ distance or ..

*Is there a sampling process that admits computing such an estimate in this situation?*

My intuition is that we can compute $p(a)/p(b)$  for any $a, b$ ($Z$ cancels!). Further, the set of all such ratios ($\{p(s)/p(t)\}$) should uniquely define $q$. If so we should have enough info to get a quantified similarity between $q, p$. So this leads me to a process: Sample $t_i\sim q, i = 1, ..., N$. Then we can indeed compute and compare $p(t_i)/p(t_j)$ to $q(t_i)/q(t_j)$ for $1\leq i \leq j \leq N$. But I'm stuck on how to turn this into a rigorous quantified similarity.

EDIT: I provided a proposed answer below. I'm open to any solution, but in particular if that answer is not sound, please comment/critique

Comment: Bootstrapping concerns *data,* but you haven't described any data!

Comment: I am proposing that we sample from p to create a dataset. Perhaps bootstrapping is the wrong term. Removing the term bootstrapping, I think the question stands--can we create a rigorous quantification of similarty between p,q given they hypotheses?

Comment: Sure you can: all such measures apply.  I believe you are trying to ask about the feasibility of *computing* such measures, not creating them.  As such, that's not a statistical question, which lead me to wonder *why* you are doing this: what statistical question are you hoping to answer?

Comment: I am hoping to compute a bound on the dissimilarity of p, q with these hypotheses. It may come in a bound of the form dissimilarity(p,q) < epsilon with probability 1-alpha. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: How large is $n$?  (It makes a difference...)

Comment: dimension $n$ ranges from about 100 to about 20K in current applications.

Comment: If anyone can provide feedback on the answer I just provided, I'd like to have someone with (presumably) more experience tell me if it is sound.

Answer (score 4):

In the situation you have described, you have $p(\mathbf{x}) = k(\mathbf{x}) / K$ where $K \equiv \int k(\mathbf{x}) \ d \mathbf{x}$ is an unknown scaling constant and the kernel function $k$ is known.  There are various measures of distance between densities, but here I will show an example using the [Kullback-Liebler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence).  This measure of divergence between the densities (with two variations taking each as the reference density) can be written in terms of the kernel function as:

$$\begin{align}
\text{KL}(p || q)
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} p(\mathbf{x}) \log \bigg( \frac{p(\mathbf{x})}{q(\mathbf{x})} \bigg) \ d \mathbf{x} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{K} \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} k(\mathbf{x}) \log \bigg( \frac{k(\mathbf{x})}{q(\mathbf{x})} \cdot \frac{1}{K} \bigg) \ d \mathbf{x} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{K} \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} k(\mathbf{x}) \log \bigg( \frac{k(\mathbf{x})}{q(\mathbf{x})} \bigg) \ d \mathbf{x} - \frac{1}{K} \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} k(\mathbf{x}) \log (K) \ d \mathbf{x} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{K} \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} k(\mathbf{x}) \log \bigg( \frac{k(\mathbf{x})}{q(\mathbf{x})} \bigg) \ d \mathbf{x} - \frac{\log (K)}{K} \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} k(\mathbf{x}) \ d \mathbf{x} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{K} \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} k(\mathbf{x}) \log \bigg( \frac{k(\mathbf{x})}{q(\mathbf{x})} \bigg) \ d \mathbf{x} - \frac{\log (K)}{K}, \\[12pt]
\text{KL}(q || p)
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} q(\mathbf{x}) \log \bigg( \frac{q(\mathbf{x})}{p(\mathbf{x})} \bigg) \ d \mathbf{x} \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} q(\mathbf{x}) \log \bigg( \frac{q(\mathbf{x})}{k(\mathbf{x})} \cdot K \bigg) \ d \mathbf{x} \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} q(\mathbf{x}) \log \bigg( \frac{q(\mathbf{x})}{k(\mathbf{x})} \bigg) \ d \mathbf{x} + \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} q(\mathbf{x}) \log (K) \ d \mathbf{x} \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} q(\mathbf{x}) \log \bigg( \frac{q(\mathbf{x})}{k(\mathbf{x})} \bigg) \ d \mathbf{x} + \log (K) \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} q(\mathbf{x}) \ d \mathbf{x} \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} q(\mathbf{x}) \log \bigg( \frac{q(\mathbf{x})}{k(\mathbf{x})} \bigg) \ d \mathbf{x} + \log (K). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

In both cases you need to adjust for the unknown scaling constant $K$ in the density $p$, though the adjustment is simpler in the latter case.  To compute the scaling constant, I recommend using [importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling) with a generating distribution that is similar in shape to the kernel function $k$.  Even in high-dimensional spaces it is usually possible to obtain a reasonable estimate of the scaling constant using an appropriate generating kernel and a large number of simulations.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this seems correct and also if there are known pitfalls in practice even if the math is correct.

We can sample from $q$, so we create the random variable $W = \frac{p(t)Z}{q(t)}, t\sim q$. (Recall $Z$ is a positive constant).

We now have:

$$ E(W) = E_q(\frac{Zp}{q}) = Z \int \frac{p}{q} dq = Z$$
and we have both

- $Var(W) = Z^2 \|p-q\|_2^2$
- $Var(W) \geq Z^2 \|p-q\|_1^2$

proven by
\begin{align} 
Var(W) & = Var_q(\frac{Zp}{q}) \\
 & = \int \left| \frac{Zp}{q} - E(W) \right|^2 dq \\
 & = Z^2 \int \left| \frac{p}{q} - 1 \right|^2 dq = Z^2\|p-q\|_2^2 \\
  & \geq Z^2 \left[ \int \left| \frac{p}{q} - 1 \right| dq \right]^2  \\
& = Z^2 \|p-q\|_1^2
\end{align}
using Jensen's inequality.

To make this a computational process, sample $t_i\sim q,$ IID for $i = 1, ..., N$ which is possible by hypothesis. Next set
$$w_i = \frac{p(t_i)Z}{q(t_i)}$$
(by hypothesis, we can compute $w_i$ given $t_i$).
Set
$$\bar{W}_N:= \frac{1}{N}\sum w_i\ .$$
By the Central Limit Theorem, we know that $\bar{W}_N \to E(W) = Z$.
We can check that $\bar{W}_N$ is Cauchy for large $N$ or use a diagnostic to try to guarantee $N$ is sufficiently large.

Next, we can compute
$$\bar{V}_{W,N} = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum (w_i - \bar{W}_N)^2
$$
and we know that $\bar{V}_{W,N} \to Var(W) = Z^2 \|p-q\|_2^2$
with convergence in probability according to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924343/showing-convergence-in-probability-of-sample-variance-to-population-variance).

Finally, the theory gives that
$$ \frac{\sqrt{ \bar{V}_{W,N} } }{\bar{W}_N} \to \|p-q\|_2 \geq \|p-q\|_1$$

which gives our bounds.

It this looks good, there are two follow-on questions to tie up the method:

- I'm proposing visually inspecting if $\bar{W}_N$ and $\bar{V}_{W,N}$ are Cauchy (settle down) as a method to know $N$ is large enough. Is there a better way?
- Can someone provide/point me to solid statistical analysis of this estimate. Something like
  $$P\left( \left| \frac{\sqrt{ \bar{V}_{W,N} } }{\bar{W}_N} - \|p-q\|_2 \right| > \epsilon \right) \leq f(\epsilon)$$

Comment: How do you propose to compute the $w_i$ if $Z$ is not computable (by assumption)?

Comment: I can compute $p(t)Z$ for any $t$. what I cannot compute is $p(t)$ nor $Z$.